# My page keeps scrolling down even after website ended

Tags: html, css

I made a website using HTML and CSS.

Two problems occurred while building this website

1. over horizontal scrolling
2. over vertical scrolling.

I corrected horizontal scrolling error by this code :

```css
* {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Just to have something, edit me</div>
```

But I don't know how to get rid of vertical scrolling :(

My website ends but page keep scrolling down to the infinite white space.

Comment: A plunkr, fiddle would be nice. Create a demo so that it's easier to provide a solution to your problem

Comment: I made a snippet of the only thing you posted from a code standpoint.  Please edit this to clearly reproduce this right here without assumption and guesses on our part.

Comment: The reason you have horizontal and vertical scrolling is because you have some element inside your page with a width and/or height that is wider and/or taller than your page's container. You need to post more code because that is how we will find your bug. Simply adding `overflow: hidden` on an axis is a band-aid. Open dev-tools and hover on elements to find one that is wider than you expect, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Comment: html { overflow-y: hidden; } ...this code freezes everything.

Comment: When answering a question, it is customary to give an explanation of how the proposed solution works, and why it will solve the questioner's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
body { overflow: hidden}
```

it freezes the background image at where I scroll to, so if I scroll to a position where white space shows beyond the background image, it will freeze there.

Then I tried scroll to where the image perfectly covering the whole screen then set the overflow - it worked.

weird.

Answer (score -1):

You have to figure out which element has very large content and apply the CSS selector to that one. For example

```
div#responsible {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: why put `div#responsible` when `#responsible ` would suffice

Comment: I know you're right; this is just to highlight the fact that usually, it's that kind of (block) element that causes the problem.